# Recursive square partitioning

Tags: java, algorithm, math, recursion

I have a trouble with understanding recursion and I couldn't solve the following problem.

**Input: An object (f.e. field) and integer n**

**Desired output: List with n fields**

I wrote a method, which divides a simple object into two parts and it works fine. But I couldn't handle the recursion.

Minimal example for createFields(field, 5) :

```
Input:
**********************************
*                                *
*                                *
*                                *
**********************************
1st iteration (after divide(field))
**********************************
*                *               *                
*                *               *
*                *               *
**********************************
2nd iteration 
**********************************
*                *               *                
**********************************
*                *               *
**********************************
3rd last iteration 
**********************************
*       *        *               *                
**********************************
*                *               *
**********************************
```

Could you help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the sizes of the fields? It seems to me that you don't want 1 half, 1 quarter, 1 eight and 2 sixteenths.

Comment: The problem is not well defined. What is a "Field"? is it only allowed to be partitioned into 2 equal parts in a single operation? Can N be a value different than a power of 2?

Comment: Yes. 5 is a value different than a power of 2. A field is a set of points *. I want a approximately equal "fields". Thank you.

Comment: If you just want to divide the largest field each time until you reach the desired number of fields, then this is actually a breath first search for which recursion is unsuitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A high level description of an algorithm would be:

```
divide_recursively (fields, n)
args:
    input/output fields : List of fields
    input n : integer (number of fields)
precondition:
    head of list is largest available field
body:
    if (fields.size() == n) return
    f = fields.front()
    fields.pop_front()
    fsplit[] = split_field(f)
    fields.push_back(fsplit[0])
    fields.push_back(fsplit[1])
    divide_recursively(fields, n)
```

The precondition is always satisfied in this algorithm so long as `split_field` splits the input exactly in half.

The algorithm is presented using recursion, since that is one of the tags in the question. This uses tail recursion, which many compilers/interpreters will convert into a regular loop as a special case of [tail call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimization.

---

The algorithm above uses a greedy approach. Below is an alternative algorithm that uses a divide and conquer approach.

```
divide_recursively (fields, n)
precondition:
    fields contains exactly one element
body:
    if (n == 1) return
    f = fields.front()
    fields.pop_front()
    fpslit[] = split_field(f)
    subfields1 = new list + fsplit[0]
    subfields2 = new list + fsplit[1]
    divide_recursively(subfields1, n/2)
    divide recursively(subfields2, n - n/2)
    fields = subfields1 + subfields2
```

Comment: Nice! However, this tail recursion can be very easily transformed into a loop. I don't see the point in recursion in this problem statement.

Comment: @EyalScheider Can you give me an example? Thank you!

Comment: @EyalSchneider: I agree, but the compiler can do that for you.

Comment: @uccie: If you are required to use recursion, then definitely this is a valid solution. But you can simply loop until the collection has size n, and then return the collection. Actually this collection should be a heap, to allow retrieving the maximum element easily.

Comment: @uccie: I correct myself; no need for the collection to be a heap. It's enough to push the new elements always to the end of the list. It's actually a queue. You can see my non-recursive suggestion in another answer.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. @EyalSchneider your solution works also, but I can not accept two answers.

Comment: @uccie: the only point I was trying to make is that this solution uses an artificial recursion. It's not really needed.

Comment: @EyalSchneider: I added an alternative algorithm that should satisfy your recursion sensibilities. However, my point is that there is no reason not to use tail recursion if the code is just as easy to understand and maintain. This is because the compiler will generate equivalent code as the non-recursive implementation.

Comment: @user315052: You are too optimistic :) there's no requirement in Java specification that the compiler do it for you (and it doesn't seem to happen in the near future). Furthermore, the JIT doesn't guarantee anything. I just tried the simplest possible tail recursion (Hotspot, with -server), and got a StackOverflowException. Try it yourself...

Comment: @EyalSchneider: Ah, that's a pity. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use your current function iteratively. You start with 1 field and call your function, which gives you a list of 2 fields. Add those to a temporary list. Now just call your split function on those fields. Once you run out of Fields of a certain size, you start by splitting the smaller fields.

The code below should give you n fields (stored in `fields` and `fields2`) of size x and x/2.

```
Field startField=...
ArrayList<Field> fields=new ArrayList<Field>();
ArrayList<Field> fields2=new ArrayList<Field>();
fields.add(startField);
nrFields=1;
outerlabel:
while(nrFields<n){
    while((!fields.isEmpty()){
        Field fieldToSplit = fields.remove(0);
        List<Field> splitFields=splitt(fieldToSplit);
        fields2.addAll(splitFields);
        nrFields++;
        if(nrFields==n)break outerlabel;
    }
    fields=fields2;
    fields2=new ArrayList<Field>();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following one of my comments, here is a proposal for a non-recursive solution (in pseudo-code):

```
split(field, n) {
    queue = new Queue()
    queue.addLast(field)
    while (queue.size() < n) {
        f = queue.removeFirst()
        pair = f.split()
        queue.addLast(pair.a)
        queue.addLast(pair.b)
    }
    return queue
```

}